# Variables of Application class are null when a new Service instance is launched

Tags: android, service

I have a `MainApplication` class which extends an `Application`.
Also I have an `AlarmBroadcastReceiver` class which extends `BroadcastReceiver`.
`onReceive(context, intent)` method of `AlarmBroadcastReceiver` gets data from `intent` and starts a service. I run service in a separate thread and this is its declaration in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<service android:name="***myPackageName***.AlarmService"
                 android:process=":remote">
</service>
```

The problem is the following: if I close the application by clicking "Home" button at Android 4.0, opening "Recent apps" and pulling the application to the left when a service is running, and then launch the application again (the service is still running), a new service, which is started when the `AlarmBroadcastReceiver` receives a new intent, can't get data of `MainApplication` class (even the static variables of the `MainApplication` are null). Why?
I can't perform debug, because the debugger is deattached when I close the application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why?

Because you added `android:process=":remote"`, which runs your service in a separate process, with its own separate copy of your `Application` object.

Simply remove `android:process=":remote"`, as using more than one process is an anti-pattern on Android anyway.

Comment: Ok, I understood about the copy of the application. Thank you very much! I will change my code...

Comment: I changed the code and now the bug is fixed. I have removed the `android:process=":remote"` and just start a service in a separate thread.